# Jumps up and down

Tags: idiomaticity

As an English-speaker I would be tempted to translate "Jack jumps up and down" into *Jack springt auf und ab*, but the English use of "up and down" seems idiomatic and my literal translation might be totally wrong. How does "Jack jumps up and down" get translated? Are there different ways of saying this in German? I've also seen *in die Luft (zu) springen*, or *ständig aufspringen* which to my American ears seems the more "German" way of saying it.

Comment: What would you say does "Jack jumps up and down" mean?

Comment: A good, idiomatic phrasing totally depends on context. You should provide more context to your sample sentece. Who is Jack? Why and where does he behave that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to translating this idiom is using the verb *hüpfen* (to hop, to skip, to frisk) instead of the verb *springen*.

*Jack jumps up and down.*

> Jack hüpft auf und ab.

This is exactly the same picture as the English expression. The alternative

> Jack springt vor Freude. (or *Jack hüpft vor Freude*.)

is very formal und sounds right only in narration. Then usually in *Präteritum* tense of course.

(Note there's another verb *hoppeln* which also means *to hop*. That's what bunnies do, people with a leg injury, and cars with broken suspension. A third verb *hopsen* means *to skip* in its narrowest sense. *Hüpfen* is a catch-all.)

Comment: I was worried that a German would think, yes, I can jump up, but there is no such thing as jumping down once you've jumped up and are at the zenith of your jump. I think I like *Jack hüpft vor Freude*, despite the poetic Klang.

Comment: *Poetic Klang* sounds like the name of a deceased Klingonian Emperor, who sang verses to the glow of a burning planet.